# Repositório no GitHub

Tags: github

A minha dúvida pode ser bem simples para alguns.

Eu tenho uma pasta local chamada "projetoX" contendo 02 subpastas, sendo (back-end e front-end), já tenho também um repositório no GitHub chamado projetoX. É possível eu enviar as subpastas que estão local (back-end e front-end) para o mesmo repositório no GitHub? Caso seja possível como faria?

Obrigado!

Comment: pracisa adicionar as pastas fazendo um `stage`, adicionar um commit com `add` e finalmente fazer um `push` para enviar tudo.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo retorno! Mais onde iniciaria o git init local, seria na pasta projetoX?

Comment: exato na pasta do ProjetoX, dai adiciona um commit com as pastas e faz o push ;)

Comment: Perfeito, nesse caso eu preciso colocar o git ignore nas subpastas locais (back-end e front-end) ou não é necessário?

Comment: não, senão elas não vão entrar automaticamente no commit. Use os ignore apenas para os arquivos que não quer mandar (binarios, executaveis, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Na pasta projectX você da um `git init`, depois da um `git commit -m "escreve um comentario"` em seguida adiciona seu repositório `git remote add origin https://github.com/seu_usuario/nome_do_repositorio.git` e por fim da um push na master `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!!!